# FuelPHP: Trying to implement Search. Routes doesn't work

Tags: php, frameworks, url-routing, fuelphp

folks. I'm kinda stuck with Routes

there is a search-form in a top-navigation.

```
<form action="/search/" class="navbar-search pull-right">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="search-query" class="search-query span3" placeholder="Go for it...">
</form>
```

So if I make a request, the URL looks like

```
fuelphp.dev/search/?q=qwerty
```

which is fine. With that URL the user should get results for his/her request provided by `action_index()`

**but** if the user goes to `fuelphp.dev/search/` (without any parameters), he/she should see the "advanced Search-form" provided by `action_advanced()`

I alredy created a Controller_Search

**classes/controller/search.php (Controller)**

```
class Controller_Search extends Controller_Hybrid
{
    public function action_index() {

        $this->template->title = 'Results for &raquo; '.Input::get('q');
        $this->template->content = View::forge('search/index.twig');
    }

    public function action_advanced()
    {
        $this->template->title = 'Search &raquo; Advanced Search';
        $this->template->content = View::forge('search/index.twig', array(
            'advancedForm' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

**views/search/index.twig (View)**

```
{% if advancedForm %}
    {% include 'advancedSearchForm.twig' %}
{% endif %}
<h4>Hello Template nesting :) </h4>
```

the problem is - I don't know how to (re)write routes for that.

if I add `'search' => 'search/advanced'` to the routes.php it doesnt work correctly.

Requestin `fuelphp.dev/search/?q=qwerty` triggers `action_advanced()` of `Controller_Search` too, whereas it should trigger `action_index()`

How should I rewrite my routes (or maybe Controller logic) to get this working ?

**UPDATE:**

The **solutuon** was found! No routes configuration needed!

```
public function action_index() {
    if (Input::get('q')) {
        $viewTitle = 'Results for &raquo; '.Input::get('q');
        $viewData = null;
    }else{
        $viewTitle = 'Search &raquo; Advanced Search';
        $viewData = Array('advancedForm' => true);
    }

    $this->template->title = $viewTitle;
    $this->template->content = View::forge('search/index.twig', $viewData);
}
```

But if one of you have a "nicer" way, I'll be glad to see it

Answer (score 1):

Try add **2 routes** one of them with a **named parameter**:

```
'search' => 'search/advanced',
'search/:q' => 'search/index/'
```

So when it has some parameter goes to `search/index` with the given parameter, but if you don't have parameters it routes to `search/advanced`

Then on `search/index` you can get the search paramer (`q`) with `$this->param('q')`

Comment: @V-Light was working for me on 1.4, what error you get? do you have any other route that could be messing up?

Comment: @pconceprion, I've got other routes, but they have nothing to do with 'search' controller
Hier is the link to [routes.php @ pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wDee0esV)

Comment: @V-Light, I meant to do something similar of what you did with movies, that depending on if it has a parameter or not it goes to a different action.

Comment: @pconceprion movies? Uhm Sakila DB :)? Alright, enough offtop. 
As you can see, i've already found a solution, but it's not the perfect one (imho). so i'll keep tring to find a workaround for two action